# R: Renaming value in the column with ( ' )

Tags: r, rename

I was given a data that looks like this

```
x <- factor(c("A","B","King's"))
```

now I want to change the value King's to C without messing with A and B.

I tried using recode from plyr,

x<- recode(x, "'King's'='C';", as. factor.result=FALSE)

but I am unable to do so because it contains ( ' )

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not positional dependent

```
levels(x)[levels(x) == "King's"] <- "C"
```

Comment: This works perfectly as well. I actually tried this last night and I just realised I only need to add a spacebar like your command.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick for you

```
x <- factor(c("A","B","King's"))
levels(x)[3] <- "C"
```

Comment: Also, levels(x)[levels(x) %in% "King's"] <- "C" which is not positional dependent as mentioned by @manotheshark and scalable to more than one factor level.

Answer (score 0):

if you like to stick with recode: (not really recommended in that case)

```
x <- recode(x, "deparse(substitute(`King's`))='C'", as.factor.result=FALSE)
```